# How do I curve Text in Illustrator CS5?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, cs5

I'm wondering how can I curve the text  below to fit the curve of the shape below. I am somewhat new to Illustrator and yes I know my version is outdated 
[image: The word "Shenanigans" horisontally, on a curved, convex background]

Comment: Hi Sentinel Gaming, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. Could you tell us what you tried that didn't work? Always good to show some effort, and your chances for a good answer increase. If you have any questions, please see the [help center](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help) or ping one of us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There are several ways to curve text in Illustrator, but the easiest is to select your text (It does not need to be outlined) and go to Effect -> Warp -> Arc... in the main menu.

[image]

The harder way (Not really that hard) is to draw an oval and use the Text on a Path tool to add text onto the ovals shape. The benefit of this method is that your text curves around the shape without being warped in any way.

[image]

Comment: It may be worth noting that an Envelope Warp or Warp Filter will distort the glyphs. It is less noticeable at smaller Bend values, but when you crank it up it becomes obvious: http://i.stack.imgur.com/7vXpC.png Because of that, I'd go with the Text on a Path (unless you intentionally want the distortion)

Answer (score 3):

1. Looking at the image above I think you should be able to use the 'make envelope' tool and adjust the curvature settings to match the object.
2. If you looking for more precision, you could use the meshwrap tool.
3. You could also try to create a curve that matches you objects curvature and type along the path.